# Share images/videos from Photos Hub via my WP app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 App. I want to add my app in the list of apps that appear when you use the ShareMediaTask. It should be possible since installing Facebook automatically adds the Facebook share to this list. So how do I register my app for this?

[image]

If this is not possible, is there a way to use FileOpenPicker() for videos??

Thanks

Comment: Why did you remove my C# tag? Of course it is C# related. It requires a XAML implementation too, but of course it needs a C# code to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to register your app to display in the Share Picker for video files.

We tried to do the same, with no success, and the same goes for photos other than JPEG files, like for example PNG.

To add a quote from the article posted by @ahandersson on "[Extending the share picker for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff967563(v=vs.105).aspx)":

This topic describes how your app can appear in the share picker, a page that lets the user pick an app for sharing the photo they are viewing. **Note that this extensibility is only available when the photo is a JPG file.**

Comment: One of the times when I hate Microsoft... Marking as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563(v=vs.105).aspx should help you register your application to display in the Share Picker.

Comment: This is a for sharing photos. I found this article yesterday and tried it, but it doesn't help my video issue.. :(